# Is it possible to "decay" SQL information?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Let's say I have rows of information in an SQL database.
I want to have rows of information that are older than 30 days to be automatically removed.

Is this possible?

Additional information:

I am using the SQL date function provided to collect the dates.

Comment: It would be helpful to know the details of the table (is there a date column?) and the database system you are using.

Comment: If you have the `Create Event` privilege you can schedule a daily SQL delete statement to run - even through php MyAdmin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem has two aspects:

- How to schedule
- Actual SQL Statement

### How to Schedule

You have multiple options, but all of this revolves around whether you will schedule, or whether you will have a stored procedure triggered.

Three options

- Use MySql event scheduling: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-overview.html
- Schedule through an operating system (CRON, SCHEDULED TASK) the execution of an app using SQL (either PHP script, java etc)
- Have a trigger that is executes a stored procedure every time a change is made to a table.

I would propose options 1 and 2 are the best.

### SQL Statement

The actual SQL statement is quite easy provided you have a field (e.g. dateField) that represents insertDate...

```
delete from myTable where insertDate < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

You can easily generate this value using the `NOW()` function within an insert statement, for example:

```
insert into myTable values (NOW(), 'value1', 'value2', ... , 'valueN');
```

### Scheduling Using Event Scheduler at End of Day

If you have the `CREATE EVENT` privilege this will work through PHP MyAdmin. 
See also: http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/

```
CREATE EVENT `clean_up2`
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS CURRENT_DATE
DO
 delete from `data` where updated_on < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In SQL Server you could create a stored procedure to perform the delete, and create a SQL Agent job that runs every day (or a schedule of your choosing)

Comment: You would have to have a field in the table giving the date of creation

Comment: True. I was assuming there was some kind of date information in the set of columns.

Comment: I should have mentioned, I am not using SQL Server.  I am using MySQL on PhpMyAdmin.